# Bash: awk returning space after result

Tags: bash

The command `awk 'END{print NR}' file.log` returns an integer, but with a space after it? How would I modify that command so there is no space returned after the result?

`awk 'END{print NR}' file.log` fetches the length of `file.log`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `printf` instead:

```
awk 'END{printf NR}' file.log
```